# Right shift two's complement number like an unsigned int

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Is this possible? I have a signed int and need to shift it right 4 places. I cannot cast the int to an unsigned int, shift and then cast back. I need to deal with it after.

So if I have a bit sequence like:

```
x = 1001
```

and need to shift it right 2 spots:

```
x = x >> 2;
```

I get 1110;

I would like to get 0010. I cant think of a way to use and's and or's to do this. Any ideas?

Specifically this is what I need.

0x12345678 replace 56 with 0xab and end up with this: 0x1234ab78

My method was get the right of 56,

int right = Ox12345

get the left of 56

int left = Ox 78

get 56

int replace = 56

return right | left | replace

and return

Ox1234ab78

Im running into issues if the number to the left of the replacement has a 1 as the MSB. Because I shift the entire thing left and then right and its transfers the 1 all the way through.

Comment: Your answer will need to involve shifts **somewhere**, even if it's just to construct bitmasks.  You'll need to specify more precisely the constraints of your homework exercise.

Comment: I'm curious: what can possibly prevent you from using the casting solution?

Comment: @Henning: It's homework. Probably the assignment specifies not to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do `x = (x >> 2) & 0x3FFFFFFF` (assuming you're talking about 32-bit integers).  This will set the 2 highest order bits to 0.

Edit:

Seeing the change in your problem, instead of your method, you can do something like this:

```
int result;
int start = 0x12345678, replace = 0xab;
result = (start & ~0xFF00) | (replace << 8);
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, this results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: Right-shifting a negative value is undefined by the C standard.

Comment: @Oli: If the OP's assignment is to right-shift a number without the sign bit carrying, I would guess that the expected result would be a fair assumption.

Comment: It is _implementation-defined_, not _undefined_.

Comment: @Random: Yes, you're right.  It's left-shifting that's undefined.

Comment: Im trying to do a swap. So if the 32 bit int is divided into sections of 8. I want to replace what is in the 2nd section with a different 8 bit number. Sometimes that number is a 1 and then the ones get transferred. I need to keep the consistency of the number before though so I cant shift to the right a few places since those 2 numbers I will need. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Daniel: As it turns out, it's implementation-defined, not undefined (see Random's comment).  If it *had* been undefined, though, you wouldn't be able to rely on this code doing anything sensible.

Comment: @Jacob: I do not understand your restatement of the problem. Could you give an example?

Comment: the number 00111100 11010011 10101010 00010100

Comment: @Jacob: What are you trying to do with that number?

Comment: So the sections are number 1 to 4 starting at the right. If I need to replace the 2nd section I will need to split the number. I place the first half in a variable a and that is 00111100 11010011 and then the second half needs to be 00010100 and then the part I need to replace is 10101010 but to get that alone I need to shift left 16 and then right 24.

Comment: @Jacob: I'm not entirely sure what the problem is. You're trying to move bits 8-15 to bits 0-7? Why do you need to left shift at all? You could just do `x = ((x >> 8) & 0xFF)`

Comment: I need to replace bits 8-15 with a difference sequence. SO I capture the beggining, middle and then the section I need to replace and then or them together.

Comment: @Jacob: I still do not understand your question.  Could you please edit the question above with more specific details and a full example of what you start with and what you want the result to be?

Comment: @Jacob: OK, I have edited my answer to solve your problem. I tested it on [codepad](http://codepad.org/yPRZDZfb) and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, since I remember doing a similar assignment in high-school where we were not allowed to use large hex numbers would be as follows:

`x = (x >> 2) & ~((1 << 31) >> 1)`.  This gives the same answer as my other answer, but takes away the need for the large hex number.